# How to animate html ::selection background-color?

Tags: javascript, variables, hue

I'd like to animate the `::selection` background-color with something similar to a hue-rotate animation. Since `::selection` background property can only contain a color or a variable, I assume  that a `::root` variable containing a color should be animated somehow and I have no clue how to animate something that can't have a class.

Maybe there's an easy solution with JS which I probably overlook now.

Vanilla JS solution preferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works now in chrome and firefox, not in safari though:

```
let r = 0;
const loop = () => {
var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
  html.style.setProperty("--changing", `hsla(${r}, 50%, 50%, 0.999)`);
  r++;
 
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

Comment: I do have to add, it works on normal text and image, but it doesn't update the color on a "a" link selection, its a funky feature anyways

Answer (score 1):

Fairly certain that this isn't possible.  The `::selection` pseudo just doesn't accept the `animation-*` properties ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection#Allowable_properties))

> Only certain CSS properties can be used with ::selection:
>
> - `color`
> - `background-color`
> - `cursor`
> - `caret-color`
> - `outline` and its longhands
> - `text-decoration` and its associated properties
> - `text-emphasis-color`
> - `text-shadow`

which makes me think it isn't possible.  We can do it with other pseudos like `::after`, but whenever I select the text, it's background color doesn't shift.

```css
.something {
  background-color: blue;
}

.something::selection {
  color: white;
  
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: colorize;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.something::after {
  content: "after";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: colorize;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes colorize {
  from {
    background-color: green;
  }
  to {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="something">Hello</span>
```

---

Even trying to constantly update a [CSS custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and "manually" animating it doesn't seem to work because the selection property doesn't get updated while it is highlighted.  For example, you can select the "Hello World!" text and you should see the red value change every time you highlight, but not ***while*** it is highlighted.

```js
const thing = document.getElementById("thing");

let r = 0;
const loop = () => {
  thing.style.setProperty("--color", `rgb(${r}, 0, 0)`);
  r++;
  if (r > 255) {
    r = 0;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
:root {
  --color: red;
}

#thing::selection {
  background-color: var(--color, black);
}
```

```html
<div id="thing">Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: since the selection background color is also a hsl color code, its probably possible to shift the "h" - hue with javascript... I know how to set a root variable with js, I just don't really know how to animate it

Comment: something like:

html.style.setProperty("--changingcolor", animated);  where "animated" would be a variable thats changing the hue value of a hsl color

and then its easy to set the selection color to that variable - and it will most likely work? Im just guessing, but it should work

Comment: @bambadamm That would still require `::selection` to support `transition-*` properties which it also doesn't.  You could try setting the variable multiple times over and over in an animated fashion, but I think that might be non-performant.

Comment: @bambadamm Actually, even that doesn't seem to work, see my edit.

Comment: ah, I see your point, well, it was worth a try :) thanks!

Comment: ive tweaked it a little bit and it actually works (except in safari) try it in chrome or ff:
https://adambernath.com/m/
the animation has to be polished a little, but its getting there!